# org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Io exception: Oracle Error ORA-12650)

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, oracle11g

I am using apache common dbcp 1.2.2 jar to create the database datasource in my project where database side we have upgraded the database Oracle 11.2.0.4.1 to Oracle 11.2.0.4.5. 
below is the my code:
where

1. driver=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
2. url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=oramtbdocq.qs2x.vwg)(PORT=1560)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=mtbdocq.qs2x.vwg)))
3. initialsize=10
4. maxidle=10
5. maxactive=10

we are using ojdbc7.jar since my jdk is 1.7

**Code 1:** *Trying to make jdbc connection by using dbcp 1.2.2 jar*

```
 try{
        org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(driver);
        dataSource.setUrl(url);
        dataSource.setUsername(username);
        dataSource.setPassword(password);
        dataSource.setInitialSize(initialsize);
        dataSource.setMaxIdle(maxidle);
        dataSource.setMaxActive(maxactive);
        basicDataSourceCon =dataSource.getConnection();
        System.out.println("\n basicDataSourceCon ::"+basicDataSourceCon);
        System.out.println("\n\n<<<<<<< --- Connected to oracle DB By BasicDataSource JDBC Connection ------ >>>>>>\n\n"); 
          }catch(Exception e2){
        System.out.println("\n <<<<<<<<<<<< Inside  BasicDataSource JDBC Connection Exception Block >>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ::");
                    e2.printStackTrace(); }
```

**Exception:**

```
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1225)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:880)
    at com.emc.xcp.bam.bamserver.listener.BamContextLoaderListener.jdbctestConnection(BamContextLoaderListener.java:265)
    at com.emc.xcp.bam.bamserver.listener.BamContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(BamContextLoaderListener.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4797)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5291)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1114)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1673)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: Oracle Error ORA-12650
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:113)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:147)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:257)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:389)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:454)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:165)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:35)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:802)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:294)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1247)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1221)
    ... 17 more
```

**But when I am using the simple jdbc connection it is going fine.**
 **Code 2:** *Simple jdbc connection which is going fine.*

```
try{

                Properties props=new Properties();
                props.put("user", username);
                props.put("password", password);
                props.put("maxIdle", maxidle);
                props.put("maxActive", maxactive);
                props.put("initialSize", initialsize);

                Class.forName(driver);
                DriverManager.getDriver(url);
                simplecon = DriverManager.getConnection(url,props);  //DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,password);
                System.out.println("\n Simple JDBC simplecon ::"+simplecon);
                System.out.println("\n\n<<<<<<< --- Connected to oracle DB By  Simple JDBC Connection ------ >>>>>>\n\n"); 
              }catch(Exception e1){
                  System.out.println("\n <<<<<<<<<<<< Inside  Simple JDBC Connection Exception Block >>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ::");
                  e1.printStackTrace(); 
               }
```

Any Idea? What could be the root cause.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it any happier with the url defined as `jdbc:oracle:thin:@//oramtbdocq.qs2x.vwg:1560/mtbdocq.qs2x.vwg`? It's not really clear - did it work as you've shown with the .1 DB release, before you patched to .5?

Comment: Hi Alex, jdbc:oracle:thin:@//oramtbdocq.qs2x.vwg:1560/mtbdocq.qs2x.vwg this jdbc url also I tried, it is working with normal jdbc connection as I shown in code 2 but failing in code 1 which is using apache common dbcp 1.2.2 jar                                          org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();

Comment: Try type casting to DataSource before getting a connection.                 import javax.sql.DataSource;                                                 basicDataSourceCon =((DataSource)dataSource).getConnection();